# Sharepoint 2013 Prerequisites installation failed: using Auto installer

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation

In the time of installing SharePoint 2013 continues to fail when running the Prerequisite Installer. It saying to update my operating system. But it is already updated till 02.03.2016(windows server 2012 Standard). The messages in a snippet is given bellow:

```
• Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5: equivalent products already installed (no action taken)
• Windows Management Framework 3.0: equivalent products already installed (no action taken)
• Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role: configuration error
• Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client: Installation skipped
• Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405): was already installed (no action taken)
• Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64): Installation skipped
• Windows Server AppFabric: Installation skipped
• Microsoft Identity Extensions: Installation skipped
• Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client: Installation skipped
• Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0: Installation skipped
• Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763): Installation skipped
```

It is the Snapshot of that messege:

[image]

and here is the snippet from the Prerequisite Installer Log:

```
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Processor architecture is (9)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Common Startup
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - The value is... 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Error: Startup task doesn't exist. This is not a continuation after a restart.
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Locating the following command line arguments file:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - D:\PrerequisiteInstaller.Arguments.txt
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Error: This file does not exist
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Details of the current operating system: 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Major version number of the operating system:  (6)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (2)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X23F0=9200)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0X110=272)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Product type of the operating system: VER_NT_SERVER
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Product type:  (7)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - OS type:  (0)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - PowerShellVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - The value is... 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - 4.0
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Install
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - The value is (1)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Version
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - The value is... 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - 4.5.51650
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - A post release .NET 4.5 is installed
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - The value is... 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - 6.1.7600.0
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading version of the following file...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - GetFileVersionInfoSize failed (-2147024894)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Version
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Windows Server AppFabric
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - ProductVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\Setup\1.0
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - 
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSIPC\CurrentVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Version
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - IsInstalled
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:34 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\KB2671763
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Beginning download/installation
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Created thread for installer
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - "C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -inputpath "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Pre8992.tmp.XML"
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Error: Unable to install (2)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Error: [In HRESULT format] (-2147024894)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Last return code (2)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Flags
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - PendingFileRenameOperations
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Error: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role.
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Last return code (2)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Options for further diagnostics: 1. Look up the return code value 2. Download the prerequisite manually and verify size downloaded by the prerequisite installer. 3. Install the prerequisite manually from the given location without any command line options.
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Cannot retry
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - PowerShellVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - The value is... 
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - 4.0
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Install
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - The value is (1)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Version
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - The value is... 
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - 4.5.51650
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - A post release .NET 4.5 is installed
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - 
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - The value is... 
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - 6.1.7600.0
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading version of the following file...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - GetFileVersionInfoSize failed (-2147024894)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Version
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Windows Server AppFabric
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - ProductVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - 
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\Setup\1.0
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - 
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSIPC\CurrentVersion
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following string value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Version
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - IsInstalled
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - from the following registry location...
2016-03-03 11:03:42 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\KB2671763
2016-03-03 11:10:34 - Opening log file
2016-03-03 11:10:34 - Opened action for user
2016-03-03 11:10:34 - C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\prerequisiteinstaller.2016.03.03-11.03.34.log
```

Comment: thnx @AsadRefai.

Comment: What is "windows server 2012 Slandered"?

Comment: sorry @JussiPalo, it was a spelling mistake. It was windows server 2012 standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to C:\windows\System32 and find "ServerManager.exe" rename it as "ServerManagerCMD.exe" then run the prerequisite installer of sharepoint. If you need more help then you can find it from [here](http://www.someshinyobject.com/posts/server-2012-r2-and-sharepoint-2013-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web)

Hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: Thnx it worked. :D 
after changing the file name the prerequisites are installed automatically with prerequisites installer. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**

Install [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2771431) and restart & retry.

**Method 2**

If Method 1 doesn't work, manually install prerequisites and restart:

Open an elevated Windows PowerShell prompt on the SharePoint server (that is, Run as Administrator), and execute the following commands:

```
Import-Module ServerManager

Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45,NET-WCF-TCP-Activation45,NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45

Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Features,Web-Server,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Static-Content,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Dir-Browsing,Web-Http-Errors,Web-App-Dev,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Net-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Health,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Log-Libraries,Web-Request-Monitor,Web-Http-Tracing,Web-Security,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering,Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,Web-Metabase,Application-Server,AS-Web-Support,AS-TCP-Port-Sharing,AS-WAS-Support, AS-HTTP-Activation,AS-TCP-Activation,AS-Named-Pipes,AS-Net-Framework,WAS,WAS-Process-Model,WAS-NET-Environment,WAS-Config-APIs,Web-Lgcy-Scripting,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Server-Media-Foundation,Xps-Viewer
```

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2765260)

Comment: tried method 1, but got the same error list. Then i tried to install the prerequisites manually, some of them worked fine, but some of the error was still here, like 
**Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role: configuration error**;
**Windows Server AppFabric: Installation skipped**;
**Microsoft Identity Extensions: Installation skipped**.

:(

Answer (score 1):

Add .NET Framework 3.5 Features and try again.

Okay, so the slightly longer answer...

During the installation of the SharePoint 2013 pre-requisites, if the .Net 3.5 features are not installed on the server, the pre-requisite installer will attempt to go to the configured source for updates for the server to retrieve .Net 3.5 and install it.

If the server is configured to go to Windows Update, this usually succeeds, however if the server is configured to use WSUS and .Net 3.5 has not been integrated into the WSUS catalog, or the server doesn't have access to the internet, this usually fails. As an alternative, the policy for 'specify settings for optional component installation and component repair' can be set to allow the server to contact Windows Update directly if the server is configured to use WSUS as its update source and .Net 3.5 has not been integrated into the WSUS catalog. Again this (obviously) requires internet access from the server to succeed.

Here's an example for a server that uses WSUS as its update source, but .Net 3.5 has not been integrated into the WSUS catalog and the policy to allow the server to access Windows Update directly for additional component installation has not been configured:
[image: Application Server Role config error]

As can be seen, the configuration of the Application Server role fails.

To install the .Net 3.5 features mount the Windows Server 2012 media in the DVD drive (mount the ISO etc.), start server manager, select 'add roles and features' from the central panel, click next until you get to the 'features' page and select '.Net framework 3.5 Features' at the top:
[image: Add .Net Framework 3.5 Features]

Click next and on the confirmation page, click 'specify an alternate path' and enter 'X:\sources\sxs' where X is the drive letter of the DVD containing the Server 2012 media:
[image: Alternate source path]

Click OK, then click 'install'. Once installation has completed, retry the installation of the SharePoint 2013 pre-requisites.

Here's a screen shot following the above process:
[image: Application Server Role config success]

As can be seen, this time, the configuration of the Application Server role is succeeding.

If you server does have access to an update source containing .Net 3.5, it will be installed automatically. Here's a screen shot of a server that this has happened on (the server used Windows Update as its update source and could therefore automatically retrieve .Net 3.5 and install it; this happens silently during the pre-requisite installation):
[image: .Net framework 3.5 Features auto installed]

Comment: This method didn't solve the problem of mine, though i installed .NET Framework 3.5 Features.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted by renaming 'ServerManager.exe' to 'ServerManagerCMD.exe'!

Answer (score 0):

This may be coming in late but I found the cause of the download errors on Prerequisite installer to be rooted in **IE Enhanced Security Configuration** default.

1. Simply open **Server Manager > Local Server**
2. Click on **IE Enhanced Security Configuration**
3. Change the settings as follows:
   [image]
4. Open IE and use it to access any website, then go back to the Prerequisite install and try again.